# PIXI 5 rendering issue with Samsung galaxy S22 and Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, samsung-mobile, pixi.js

For some reasons on Samsung galaxy S22 using the Chrome browser PIXI cannot render shapes using PIXI.Graphics. Anybody else having similar issues ? Did your found a workaround ?

Comment: Please create issue in https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/issues  . You should provide working example (source code via codesandbox or www.pixiplayground.com etc ) and as many details as possible (pixi version, browser version, if in any other browser it is working, screenshots etc). Otherwise it will be hard to suggest any solution.

Comment: Note there are two variants of S22, one build on Snapdragon another one on Exynos (with new Xclipse 920 graphics) mainly for European market.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. If you are using PIXI.Graphics to draw shapes and it's not rendering. Disable webGL and use canvas instead. Not the best but it's working. I hope Google come with a fix at some point.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).